# Java: why equal method is not called when searching for same variable in hashmap

Tags: java

Here is my test class..

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(0, 1);
        HashMap<A, Integer> map = new HashMap<A, Integer>();
        map.put(a, (a.x + a.y));
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(a));
        System.out.println("----------------- ");
        System.out.println(map.containsKey(new A(0, 1)));
    }

}
```

and here is my class A with hashcode and equal method generated by eclipse.

```
class A {
    int x, y;

    public A(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println(" in hashcode");
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println(" in equal");
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        A other = (A) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

The output of program is

```
 in hashcode
 in hashcode
true
----------------- 
 in hashcode
 in equal
true
```

My questions are: (I know the contract of hashcode and equal and why it is used)

1. Why in first case hashcode method is called twise ?
2. Why in first case equal does not called ? How JVM know that it is the same variable we are searching?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) getHashCode is called one when you call put, then again when you call contains.

2) in the first case, the hashmap contains a reference to a, i.e. the address of a in memory, so there is no need to call equals. In the second case, the table lookup finds a, but this is a different object from the new A that you gave as a parameter, so there is a need to call equals() to find out if they are equal (they could be different and have the same hash code, this would be a collision).

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the source code of HashMap.containsKey you'll find the following (taken from here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29 )

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getEntry(key) != null;
}


final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
    e != null;
    e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
        ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
        return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The important part is this `(k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))`. The metod first compares key objects by reference and then uses equals method for comparison but only if the references are different.

In your first call to `containsKey` key references will be the same (the same object). In second call references will be different (different instances of an "equal" object), hence call to `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

As you can view in @kresimir-nesek pasted code,

First get the hashCode: `int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());` and prints **" in hashcode"**

Then compare the java object identifier, `(k = e.key) == key`

1) in the first case is the same and return true. Calling to map.put you get the second  **" in hashcode"**

2) but in the second case the object identifier is different, so call to equals (...`(key != null && key.equals(k))`...)

**" in equal"**